# ho to fix the gradle project sync failed

Tags: android

i'm completely new to android studios.
While creating my first project it shows an error in XML view as**Gradle  project sync failed ** which u could found in my screenshot and help me fix it and i'm working in Ubuntu 16.04 [screenshot showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4OzH.png).

Answer (score 1):

Close Android Studio

Go to `/home/dhepak/.gradle/caches` and delete (or move to have a backup) everything in this folder.

Restart Android Studio

There is a '`cache.properties.lock`' that is holding a global lock which is preventing you from running your script.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Android Studio -> Clean Project -> Make Project -> Rebuild Project ->  Run